# Getting Intelij version error when I try to run a guidewire project, how do i solve it?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I'm trying to run a guidewire project using gwb studio command, I have java 11 jdk  and intelij version 2021.1.3 installed and added to environment variable, however when I try to build the project in command prompt using gwb studio, I'm getting below error :

> Blockquote

You are running a version of Studio that does not have a bundled IntelliJ.
** IDEA_HOME must be set to contain the path to an installation of IntelliJ 2022.3
**
** Studio cannot be started until this is fixed.

> Blockquote

how can i fix this ?

tried uninstalling and reinstalling intelij

Answer (score 1):

According to your error, you have the wrong version of intellij.

IDEA_HOME must be set to contain the path to an installation of IntelliJ 2022.3